# R: Compose multiple images into one image

Tags: r, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to compose/combine different images to one image.

Specific: I have images of individual coins.
Now I want an image with, e.g., 20 coins in one image (out of the images with the individual coins). The coins are **not** allowed to **overlap** or to be cut off. The coins should be placed **randomly** in the image. Next, the coins should also be **rotated** (this means not only quadratic images).

[Example single coin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZc8g.jpg)

[Goal: Image with many coins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMedL.jpg)

I'm using the R library "**magick**" to read/write/transform images.

I've tried "append", "mosaic", "montage", and "image_composite".

The only function that nearly got the right output was "**image_composite**", but I don't know how to handle the offset as the coins should be placed randomly but are not allowed to overlap.

(Example, images are already loaded:)

```
img = background
img = image_composite(img, coin1, offset = "+100+100")
img = image_composite(img, coin2, offset = "+644+100")
print(img)
```

Which function could I use instead or how could I handle the offset (e.g., like a map of "used" space where I can determine free space for the next coin)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can see here how to handle offsets http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html

Comment: Are you using only one coin repeatedly at different sizes? Or are you providing multiple sized coins as the input?

Comment: I'm using different coins and therefore they are different sized.